# Emigrating to Canada with IELTS

Tags: canada

Today, one of my friends told me that Canada has a special program for IELTS test takers. If you can collect enough points, the Canadian embassy issues you a visa, although I am uncertain of the type of visa. Is there any truth to that?

Answer (score 7):

There is no visa program for Canada that allows people to immigrate based *solely* on their English ability. However, an IELTS score (or an [equivalent French assessment test](http://www.fiaf.org/frenchclasses/frenchexam-tef.shtml)) may be required.

From [Do you want to come to Canada, or extend your stay?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/getting-started.asp):

> You may be asked questions about your:
>
> - nationality
> - age
> - language ability
> - family members
> - education
> - work experience
> - income and/or net worth
> - details on any job offer
>
> Based on your answers, we will tell you what programs you may be eligible for, so be as accurate as you can.

As you can see, "language ability" is just one of the kinds of things they might ask you.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind but my friend wanted me to ask it anyway.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

IELTS and French Assessment Test is one of the parameter where there total points are included in Express entry VISA. If you want to apply as a Skilled Worker VISA there is Point based system "http://canada-da.com/calculator.html", majorly calculated on IELTS score, French Language known, any sibling/relatives in Canada, Money you bring in Canada, Education level, Age, Gender, Work Experience. There are also various VISA category you can check on CIC website.